# How to get image from the firestore to this gridview. Error "Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'."

Tags: flutter

I added product images to the firestore as an array of 3 items. Now I need to get one of the image to the home screen gridview but I can't do it. Someone please help. Here is the code of the products.dart page.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vegishoppi/pages/product_details.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  CollectionReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
  var product_list = [
    {
      "name": "Beans",
      "picture": "Images/Beans.jpg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    {
      "name": "Carrot",
      "picture": "Images/Carrot.jpg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    {
      "name": "Cauliflower",
      "picture": "Images/Cauliflower.jpg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    {
      "name": "Palak",
      "picture": "Images/Palak.jpg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    {
      "name": "Radish",
      "picture": "Images/Radish.jpg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    }
  ];


  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Center(child: const Text('Loading events...'));
    }
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Image.network(snapshot.data[index].image);
      },
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    ); //Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name']);
    },
    );
  }

class Single_prod extends StatelessWidget {
  final prod_name;
  final prod_picture;
  final prod_old_price;
  final prod_price;

  Single_prod({
    this.prod_name,
    this.prod_picture,
    this.prod_old_price,
    this.prod_price,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
          tag: new Text("hero 1"),
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductDetails(
                    product_details_name: prod_name,
                    product_details_new_price: prod_price,
                    product_details_old_price: prod_old_price,
                    product_details_picture: prod_picture,
                  ))),
              child: GridTile(
                  footer: Container(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child:Text(prod_name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 
                      16.0),),
                      ),

                      new Text("\₹${prod_price}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontWeight: 
                     FontWeight.bold),)
                    ],)
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    prod_picture,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

It doesnt get the image to the app. Also I have the images in firestore as arrays, I only need the first image out of 3. Someone please helkp me with this. I followed Santos Enoque's tutorial for developing this.

Comment: try this **snapshot.data.documents[index].image** to access your specific index document

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of collection reference

```
  class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {``
         // replace this CollectionReference ref = 
    //Firestore.instance.collection("products"); with
    List<DocumentSnapshot> product=[];
    bool isLoading=false;
    @override
    void initState() {

                   super.initState();
                     getProductList();
                }

       getProductList() async {
           setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
                });

           print("geting instance for product");
        QuerySnapshot qp;
        qs = await Firestore.instance
              .collection("products")
               .getDocuments();

        product.isEmpty ? product.addAll(qs.documents) : null;

        setState(() {
             isLoading = false;
                   });
            }


        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
           SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return isLoading ?  Text('Loading events...') : 
        Image.network(product[index].data["image"]);//this works when the image link 
        //  is 
        // stored in firestore if link is not present in the firestore ping //me
             },
         itemCount: product.length,
                          ); 
                   },
         );
     }
```

[Firestore snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NjTJ.png)

Comment: if you have not stored links of the images in firestore i will suggest to store them in google drive and paste the id of the file in the product collection with image field name

Comment: then add

Image.network(product[index].data["image"]); as

Comment: Image.network("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${product[index].data["image"]}"); 



this will definitely work

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I tried using this code, there was no error but It doesn't display the items.

Comment: it will display when you have the link of the image for accessing the image
The  Image.network("link of the image") that's the reason why I have given an example of storing the image in  drive and give the link of the image in the firestore
it will definitely work

Comment: can you provide tha snapshot of the data stored in tha firestore

Comment: Sure, I have added the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

For example, take this as an example
the product collects has two documents which have image as their key and value as the link of the image

take this as an example of the data in firestore[click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2kFY.png)